# SCIP using Matlab interface

Tags: matlab, scip

I am trying to  use SCIP 3.1.1 along with Matlab in Windows environment

When I run the installscip.m file I get the prompt message that  interface Library folder is missing.

/lib/liblpispx.

Can anyone please guide me what step did I skip?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please be more specific with your question. What does the installscip.m do? Where does it come from? How is the prompt triggered? Have you tried to find out what liblpispx is?

Comment: Thank you .     The problem is am unable to find the libraries.     This prompt is triggered when I try to run the command installscip.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to run SCIP in Matlab is by using the [OPTI Toolbox](http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/). SCIP should be already included, so you don't have to install it yourself.

The current OPTI Toolbox is using SCIP 3.0.1, though.

Comment: thanks Matt. I tried that as well. But I get the error as                                          Attempt to execute SCRIPT scip as a function:                                                                                                               When I give the option for solver as CBC it works well. But it fails for SCIP.

Comment: I did Post installation test for OPTI Toolbox and you  can see the log it says                          


SCIP:            Not Available

Comment: This seems to be a OPTI specific question/problem. You may have better success finding a solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opti-toolbox-forum)